Graph traversing for Pattern Searching
A given string only consisting of the letters A,G,C and T are given. Let's call this S. Another string L with the same letters is given so that 2 ≤ |S| ≤ |L| ≤ 100.
My job is to find and keep count of different occurrences of S in L and "changed S" is L.
Lets say S = "ACG"
The strings I search for in L are:
Type 1: S
Type 2: "AC", "CG", "AG" (S but any one character is removed)
Type 3: "ACGA", "ACAG", "ACGG" (S but any one of the allowed characters are inserted in the string)
I have tried to make an automat in python that keeps track of the occurrences while changing stages depending on different inputs from L starting such as:
for i in range(len(L))
Automat(L[i])
However I can't get it to work with the if statements in the automat.
Now I am trying try to make a graph of S and the permutations of S so I can implement a search algorithm that traverses the graph (without cycles), but can quit searching an entire branch of the graph if for example A is not in L than S without any changes is not in L, as well as "ACGA", "AC" and "AG" are not searched for. But can't find a way to structure it. Does anyone have some input that could help?
